# Margin is not respected in Outlook clients

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

I'm composing an HTML email and i run into this problem. There are 5 images that should be responsive and break a line on lower res.
Everything is fine in other clients but outlook doesn't respect `Margin`, `padding` or even transparent `border`.

How can I layout those to work in outlook?
[image: Margin is not repsected]
[image: Code]

Answer (score 0):

The Outlooks on Windows (from 2007 and above) use Word as a rendering engine. They don't support `display:inline-block` and have limited support for `margin`. The most common recommandation is to use tables for layout for the Outlooks. Since you already have a satisfying result in other email clients, you can use [conditional comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537512(v%3Dvs.85)) to only add a table for the Outlooks on Windows. Other email clients will ignore it and understand your regular CSS instead.

Here’s an example:

```html
<!--[if mso]>
<table align="center" style="border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse;" role="presentation"><tr><td style="padding:15px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">
<![endif]-->
<a style="vertical-align:top; margin:15px !important; display:inline-block; text-align:center" href="https://www.example.com">…</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</td><td style="padding:15px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">
<![endif]-->
<a style="vertical-align:top; margin:15px !important; display:inline-block; text-align:center" href="https://www.example.com">…</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</td><td style="padding:15px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">
<![endif]-->
<a style="vertical-align:top; margin:15px !important; display:inline-block; text-align:center" href="https://www.example.com">…</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</td><td style="padding:15px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">
<![endif]-->
<a style="vertical-align:top; margin:15px !important; display:inline-block; text-align:center" href="https://www.example.com">…</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</td><td style="padding:15px; vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">
<![endif]-->
<a style="vertical-align:top; margin:15px !important; display:inline-block; text-align:center" href="https://www.example.com">…</a>
<!--[if mso]>
</td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
```